# Handle WebFaultException to display error message on label

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest

In my WCF REST service, there is a method GetUser(username), which will

```
throw new WebFaultException<string>("there is no this user", HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
```

In my asp.net client, I want to catch above exception and show "there is no this user" on a label. But when I try coding as follow:

```
MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient;
try
{
    client.GetUser(username);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Label.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

It turns out show the message "NotFound" instead of "there is no this user".

How can i do to show the message "there is no this user"?

---

20/4

In my REST service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "{username}")]
void GetUser(username);
```

.svc class :

```
 public void GetUser(username)
    {
        try
        {
            Membership.GetUser(username);
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new WebFaultException<string>("there is no this user", HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the documentation, it's obvious that you should be showing the `Detail`, not the `Message`.  Your line should be:

```
MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient;
try
{
    client.GetUser(username);
}
catch (FaultException<string> ex)
{
    var webFaultException = ex as WebFaultException<string>;
    if (webFaultException == null)
    {
       // this shouldn't happen, so bubble-up the error (or wrap it in another exception so you know that it's explicitly failed here.
       rethrow;
    }
    else
    {
      Label.Text = webFaultException.Detail;
    }
}
```

**EDIT: changed exception type**

Also, you should be catching the specific exception (`WebFaultException<string>`) that you're interested in, not any-old exception that happens to be thrown.  Especially, as you'll only have the `Detail` on the `WebFaultException<string>` type, it's not on `Exception`.

See the [WebFaultException Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd989924.aspx)

Comment: but when i change Exception to WebFaultException<string>, it cannot reach the catch{}, it throw a exception in " client.GetUser(username);" It shows" FaultException was unhandled by user code"

Comment: Have you tried changing the `WebFaultException<string>` to `FaultException<string>`.  It would seem from what you say that the actual type of exception thrown is a `FaultException`, and you want a `WebFaultException`, I've updated the code to reflect this.  Does it work?

Comment: doesn't work, although it can reach catch{}, webFaultException is null, cannot show error message.

Comment: Well, looking at the problem again, if you're intending on having a REST service, you shouldn't be using the FaultExceptions at all, they are for SOAP-based WCF services, which are *completely* different.  Are you using any frmework for your REST service?  How are you defining it as REST?

Comment: i just use vs2010 to create it. i have post my service code, Please take a look at my edited question.